# Is there an STL algorithm to find the last instance of a value in a sequence?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, find

Using STL, I want to find the last instance of a certain value in a sequence.

This example will find the *first* instance of 0 in a vector of ints.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> intvec;
intvec values;
// ... ints are added to values
intvec::const_iterator split = std::find(values.begin(), values.end(), 0);
```

Now I can use `split` to do things to the subranges `begin()` .. `split` and `split` .. `end()`.  I want to do something similar, but with split set to the *last* instance of 0.  My first instinct was to use reverse iterators.

```
intvec::const_iterator split = std::find(values.rbegin(), values.rend(), 0);
```

This doesn't work because `split` is the wrong type of iterator.  So ...

```
intvec::const_reverse_iterator split = std::find(values.rbegin(), values.rend(), 0);
```

But the problem now is that I can't make "head" and "tail" ranges like `begin(), split` and `split, end()` because those aren't reverse iterators.  Is there a way to convert the reverse iterator to the corresponding forward (or random access) iterator?  Is there a better way to find the last instance of an element in the sequence so that I'm left with a compatible iterator?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> But the problem now is that I can't
>   make "head" and "tail" ranges using
>   begin() and end() because those aren't
>   reverse iterators.

`reverse_iterator::base()` is what you are looking for - section *new members* on [SGIs reverse_iterator description](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/ReverseIterator.html) or [here on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base)

Comment: Note that `reverse_iterator::base()` doesn't point to the same element, but instead to the element after the found item.  Scott Meyer's expressed it best in guideline 3 in this article: http://www.ddj.com/cpp/184401406

Comment: [std::reverse_iterator::base](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base) entry at cppreference

Answer (score 6):

What about [std::find_end](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_end/)? (To find the last occurrence of a sequence)

Comment: +1 for interesting approach.  Looking for the last subsequence of one element certainly would work.  But converting the reverse iterator to it's base type is more efficient.